# Creating a function to load data into a list? Passing filename to import through function

Tags: python, function

I am new to writing functions and modules, and I need some help creating a function within my new module that will make my currently repetitive process of loading data much more efficient.

I would like this function to reside in a larger overall module with other function that I can keep stored on my home directory and not have to copy into my working directory every time I want to call one of my function.

The data that I have is just some JSON Twitter data from the streaming API, and **I would like to use a function to load the data (list of dicts) into a list that I can access after the function runs** by using something like `data = my_module.my_function('file.json')`.

I've created a folder in my home directory for my python modules and I have two files in that directory: `__init__.py` and `my_module.py`.

I've also went ahead and added the python module folder to `sys.path` by using `sys.path.append('C:\python')`

Within python module folder, the file `__init__.py` has nothing in it, it's just an empty file.

**Do I need to put anything in the** `__init__.py` **file?**

`my_module.py` **has the following code:**

```
import json

def my_function(parameter1):
    tweets = []
    for line in open(parameter1):
        try: 
            tweets.append(json.loads(line))
        except:
            pass
```

**I would like to cal the function as such:**
    import my_module
    data = my_module.my_function('tweets.json')

What else do I need to do to create this function to make loading my data more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import the module from the package, for example:

```
import my_package.my_module as my_module
```

would do what you want. In this case it's fine to leave the **init**.py empty, and the module will be found just by it being in the package folder "my_package". There are many alternatives on how to define a package/module structure and how to import them, I encourage you to read up, as otherwise you will get confused at some point.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like this function to reside in a larger overall module with
>   other function that I can keep stored on my home directory and not
>   have to copy into my working directory every time I want to call one
>   of my function.

For this to work, you need to create a `.pth` file in `C:\Python\site-packages\` (or wherever you have installed Python). This is a simple text file, and inside it you'd put the path to your module:

```
C:/Users/You/Some/Path/
```

Call it `custom.pth` and make sure its in the `site-packages` directory, otherwise it won't work.

> I've also went ahead and added the python module folder to sys.path by
>   using sys.path.append('C:\python')

You don't need to do this. The site-packages directory is checked by default for modules.

In order to use your function as you intend, you need to make sure:

1. The file is called `my_module.py`
2. It is in the directory you added to the `.pth` file as explained earlier

That's it, nothing else needs to be done.

As for your code itself the first thing is you are missing a return statement.

If each line in the file is a json object, then use this:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import json

def my_function(parameter1):
    tweets = []
    with open(parameter1) as inf:
       for line in inf:
           try: 
               tweets.append(json.loads(line))
           except:
               pass
    return tweets
```

If the enter file is a json object, then you can do this:

```
def my_function(parameter1):
    tweets = None
    with open(parameter1) as inf:
         tweets = json.load(inf)
    return tweets
```